# Is there any way to combine two array with different size in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There are two arrays and their shapes are (5,5) and (3,3).

```
(5, 5)
[[5. 5. 5. 5. 5.],
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.],
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.],
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.],
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]
(3, 3)
[[1. 1. 1.],
 [1. 1. 1.],
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

I want the result as an 5x8 array just like below

```
 [[5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1],
  [5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1],
  [5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1],
  [5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0],
  [5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an empty array with the final size (like a np.zeros(5,8)) and then fill it

without using a for loop you can assign the 2 arrays as slice of the empty array

```
final = np.zeros(5,8)
final[:4,:4] = array1 
final[:3,5:] = array2
```

Comment: Do you mean that I need to use for loop to fill the array? Since my task is to combine two arrays which are (60000,10) and (9600,15), I want it to be (69600, 25)

Comment: @Ksensei yes that was my idea, but with those dimensions,a  brute force approach like this is not ideal.. it will work but surely not ideal

Comment: @Ksensei, your second example do not match your question, according to your question you need to obtain a (60000,25) array.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_a = [[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
array_b = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

row_a = 5
column_a = 5

row_b = 3
column_b = 3

final_row = max(row_a, row_b)
final_col = column_a + column_b


def convert_array(array, row, col, target_row, target_col, from_left_to_right=True):
  for col_index in range(col, target_col):
    for row_index in range(0, row):
      if from_left_to_right:
        array[row_index].append(0)
      else:
        array[row_index].insert(0, 0)

  for row_index in range(row, target_row):
    array.append([])
    for col_index in range(0, target_col):
      array[row_index].append(0)


# convert array a to an array with the same size of the final array
convert_array(array_a, row_a, column_a, final_row, final_col, from_left_to_right=True)
print array_a

# convert array b to an array with the same size of the final array
convert_array(array_b, row_b, column_b, final_row, final_col, from_left_to_right=False)
print array_b

# merge array
ret = []
for row_index in range(0, final_row):
  ret.append([])
  for col_index in range(0, final_col):
    value = array_a[row_index][col_index] ^ array_b[row_index][col_index]
    ret[row_index].append(value)

print ret
```

```
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0]]
```